# Why can't I open my Launch activity from within my app

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have a main activity MainActivity that is the entry point to my android app. It launches via the Launcher correctly. However, when I try to do a startActivity, I see some debug that the activity is trying to launch, and some code fires correctly, but the MainActivity never starts.

I think it may be intent-filter related:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Is this correct?

From an internal activity, I have

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent...
    startActivity(intent);
  }
});
```

I even see

10-11 22:23:46.026: INFO/ActivityManager(472): START {flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.foo/.ui.MainActivity u=0} from pid 1541

in the logs so I know the button is wired, I just never get the new Activity :/

Comment: So you are trying to launch a second activity from your main activity?

Comment: In this part, `new Intent...`, what do you actually have? That could be causing your problem.

Comment: Did removing the second `intent-filter` fix your problem?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately it did not.

Comment: @codeMagic I'm actually using Routable which fires the intent for me. I don't think its relevant though, because I see it try and call startActivity for me and the intent looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused by the two `intent-filter` declarations. I don't think that's necessary for what you're trying to accomplish. Changing the activity section to:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

should solve your problem.

Comment: That's what I had, doesn't seem to work.         <activity
            android:name=".ui.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>